# Trying to reach my container I got "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: php, apache, docker

I've tried to run this command

- `docker run -t -i -d --name demo -p 8080:80 ubuntu-apache2-img`

Then I've looked for all my containers

- `docker ps -a`
- `8fffa1a8da7b        ubuntu-apache2-img   "/bin/bash"         59 minutes ago      Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   demo`

Ho cercato l'IP del mio container

- `docker inspect 8fffa1a8da7b | grep '"IPAddr' | awk '{print $2}'`
- `"172.17.0.45",`

And If I try to open http://172.17.0.45:8080 from my host, i get "This site can’t be reached"

Why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `127.0.0.1:8080` since you've published the port onto the host?

Comment: You shouldn't be using Docker's internally managed IP addresses. You've exposed port 80 on your server (which may not be local) as @JonStirling has pointed out. If you're trying this on a *local* machine using Docker Machine you will need to find the Docker Machine's IP. Can you tell us more about your setup?

Comment: As @JonStirling said: it should be `127.0.0.1:8080`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using docker host ? If so, you might want to change the IP address (container IP) with your docker host IP address.

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions.